# Compare columns in two files and if match change string in another column

Tags: unix, awk, grep

I have two files

```
file1 
non-coding  X   FlyBase gene    20025099    20025170    .   +   .   gene_id "FBgn0052826"; gene_symbol "tRNA:Pro-CGG-1-1";
non-coding  X   FlyBase gene    19910168    19910521    .   -   .   gene_id "FBgn0052821"; gene_symbol "CR32821";
non-coding  X   FlyBase gene    476857  479309  .   -   .   gene_id "FBgn0029523"; gene_symbol "CR18275";
non-coding  X   FlyBase gene    15576355    15576964    .   +   .   gene_id "FBgn0262163"; gene_symbol "betaNACtes5";
non-coding  X   FlyBase gene    19910168    19910521    .   -   .   gene_id "FBgn0052821"; gene_symbol "CR32821";

file2
betaNACtes5
CR18275
28SrRNA-Psi:CR45859
CR32821
```

What I want: if there is a match of any line in file2 with column 13 (partial match because of the " ") of file1 I want to change the string in column 4 to "pseudogene" otherwise nothing should be done.

```
Desired output

non-coding  X   FlyBase gene    20025099    20025170    .   +   .   gene_id "FBgn0052826"; gene_symbol "tRNA:Pro-CGG-1-1";
non-coding  X   FlyBase pseudogene  19910168    19910521    .   -   .   gene_id "FBgn0052821"; gene_symbol "CR32821";
non-coding  X   FlyBase gene    476857  479309  .   -   .   gene_id "FBgn0029523"; gene_symbol "CR18275";
non-coding  X   FlyBase pseudogene  15576355    15576964    .   +   .   gene_id "FBgn0262163"; gene_symbol "betaNACtes5";
non-coding  X   FlyBase pseudogene  19910168    19910521    .   -   .   gene_id "FBgn0052821"; gene_symbol "CR32821";
```

So far I can get the matches, but I can't do the rest.

```
grep -Ff file2 file1
```

Comment: That grep command isn't matching correctly as it'll do a partial match anywhere in the line rather than a full word match in just the field you're interested in. Does the white space between fields need to be preserved?

Comment: yes, the white space should be preserved

Comment: Please do fix that expected output so this question makes sense to others with similar questions in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match() and `\s/\S` shorthand:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    genes["\""$1"\";"]
    next
}
$NF in genes {
    match($0,/((\S+\s+){3})\S+(.*)/,a)
    $0 = a[1] "pseudogene" a[3]
}
{ print }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file2 file1
non-coding  X   FlyBase gene    20025099    20025170    .   +   .   gene_id "FBgn0052826"; gene_symbol "tRNA:Pro-CGG-1-1";
non-coding  X   FlyBase gene    19910168    19910521    .   -   .   gene_id "FBgn0052821"; gene_symbol "CR32821";
non-coding  X   FlyBase pseudogene    476857  479309  .   -   .   gene_id "FBgn0029523"; gene_symbol "CR18275";
non-coding  X   FlyBase pseudogene    15576355    15576964    .   +   .   gene_id "FBgn0262163"; gene_symbol "betaNACtes5";
```

alternatively, using any POSIX awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    genes["\""$1"\";"]
    next
}
$NF in genes {
    match($0,/([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){3}/)
    tail = substr($0,RLENGTH+1)
    sub(/[^[:space:]]+/,"",tail)
    $0 = substr($0,1,RLENGTH) "pseudogene" tail
}
{ print }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file2 file1
non-coding  X   FlyBase gene    20025099    20025170    .   +   .   gene_id "FBgn0052826"; gene_symbol "tRNA:Pro-CGG-1-1";
non-coding  X   FlyBase gene    19910168    19910521    .   -   .   gene_id "FBgn0052821"; gene_symbol "CR32821";
non-coding  X   FlyBase pseudogene    476857  479309  .   -   .   gene_id "FBgn0029523"; gene_symbol "CR18275";
non-coding  X   FlyBase pseudogene    15576355    15576964    .   +   .   gene_id "FBgn0262163"; gene_symbol "betaNACtes5";
```

Comment: Thanks I am getting this error ```awk: syntax error at source line 6 source file tst.awk
 context is
     >>>  match($0,/((\S+\s+){3})\S+(.*)/, <<< 
awk: illegal statement at source line 6 source file tst.awk
awk: illegal statement at source line 6 source file tst.awk```

Comment: Then you aren't using GNU awk as I mentioned is required.

Comment: I added a POSIX solution too.

Comment: I tried it and it works very well! Thanks a lot. I installed gawk and will try that too.

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. This will preserve whitespaces present in Input_file1 also.

```
awk '
BEGIN{ s1="\"" }
FNR==NR{
  arr[s1 $0 s1";"]
  next
}
{
  match($0,/^([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){3}/)
  firstPart=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  match($0,/^[^ ]+/)
  restPart=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  print firstPart ($NF in arr?"pseudogene":substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)) restPart
}
' file2 file1
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                          ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{ s1="\"" }                               ##Setting s1 to " in BEGIN section.
FNR==NR{                                       ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE when file2 is being read.
  arr[s1 $0 s1";"]                             ##Creating arr array with index of s1 current line s1 semi colon here.
  next                                         ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
{
  match($0,/^([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){3}/)  ##using match function to match 1st 3 fields here.
  firstPart=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)          ##Saving matched part into firstPart to be used later on.
  $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)                 ##Saving rest of the matched line into current line.
  match($0,/^[^ ]+/)                           ##matching everything from starting till 1st space in current line to get 4th field and rest of line value here.
  restPart=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)           ##Creating restpart variable which has everything after 4th field value here.
  print firstPart ($NF in arr?"pseudogene":substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)) restPart ##Printing firstPart then pseudogene OR 4th field and restPart as per need.
}
' file2 file1                                  ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked perfectly, it correctly changed the 340 instances where i expected the word pseudogene appear.

Comment: @Amaranta_Remedios, your welcome, cheers and happy learning. I will add detailed explanation in few mins, after my dinner too.

Comment: Thanks, that will be useful fo rme to learn. Have a nice dinner :)

Comment: @Amaranta_Remedios, Added detailed explanation for my code now.

Comment: I just realised it has created a problem in the output but just for the "pseudogene" entries. It has deleted several columns for those entries ```non-coding X FlyBase gene 20025099 20025170 . + . gene_id "FBgn0052826"; gene_symbol "tRNA:Pro-CGG-1-1";
non-coding X FlyBase pseudogene "FBgn0052821"; gene_symbol "CR32821";
non-coding X FlyBase pseudogene "FBgn0029523"; gene_symbol "CR18275";```

Comment: If there are cases not covered by the example in your question that don't work for posted answers then edit your question to included those cases in your sample input/output. Don't try to add them in comments where they can't be formatted and can be missed.

Comment: @Amaranta_Remedios, Sorry but when I run my code I see, expected output as per your shown samples, also I checked this with Ed's answer looks like both codes are giving same output(not comparing here but for double check output I have tested).

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 i am checking if i missed something in my question. Sorry if i have created a confusion, the file is bigger than the snippet chosen as example.

Comment: @Amaranta_Remedios, even with your updated input I could see output is coming fine. Please explain what is not working here?

Comment: I have no idea (I am very sorry), I tried again and it keep missing everything after pseudogene until gene_ID ( 20025099 20025170 . + . gene_id )

Comment: @Amaranta_Remedios, could you please do run command `cat -v file1` and `cat -v file2` on both files to see if you have any control M characters in them?

Comment: I did, no hidden ^M in files

Comment: @Amaranta_Remedios, not sure, it worked for me with shown samples. Is your expected output shown in your question is correct?

Comment: yes, if there is a match i just want the column that reads gene to change to pseudogene